# how to Show/Hide text field based on drop down selection in rails3

Tags: html-select, textfield

What is the best way to Show/Hide text field based on drop down selection in rails3?

here is the code

```
 <label>Album </label>
  <%= select_tag "album", options_for_select(@album_fields, params[:album])" %>

 <!--ONLY DISPLAY the label and text_field  if one of the selection  IS SELECTED-->

  <label>New Album Name: </label>
  <%= text_field "new_album_name", params[:new_album_name], :id =>"albumname" %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have JavaScript enabled in the browser, you can do this with jQuery.

Basically you hook into the drop-down's [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event, and when that happens, you check the value of the drop-down and either show or hide the text-field based on what was selected in the drop-down.

Something like:

```
$("#drop_down_id").change(function() {
   if (I should hide the text field)
     $("#text_field_id").hide();
   else
     $("#text_field_id").show();
});
```